# jQuery mouseover/mouseout delay, multiple elements

Tags: jquery, delay, mouseover, mouseout

I have this series of parent divs (sharing the same class) that enclose a child each.
When I mouseover a parent, I want to add a class to its child.
When I mouseout, I want to remove that class with a 500ms delay.

I figured setTimeout was the way to go for the delay.
To prevent mouseout from triggering the removeClass after I actually got back over the parent, I thought of using clearTimeout.
The problem is I cannot get clearTimeout to be triggered **only if** the newly hovered parent is the same as the previous one. The result of this being that if I hover from parent A to parent B in less than 500ms, removeClass is not triggered on parent A (as I actually would like it to).

I hope this makes sense. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
var timer

$('.parent')
  .mouseover(function() {
    //clearTimeout(timer)
    $(this).children('.child').addClass('red');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    that = this
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $(that).children('.child').removeClass('red');
    }, 500);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/1wnp82nm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set timeout specific to each `.parent` element and bind relevant context to `setTimeout` callback, e.g using `bind()` to avoid variable `that` closure issue:

### -DEMO-

```
$('.parent')
  .mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    $(this).children('.child').addClass('red');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).children('.child').removeClass('red');
    }.bind(this), 500);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.
Now... If I wanted to affect the siblings of the hovered parent (rather than its child), how would I deal with the binding?

https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/mhrg62w6/